# iPhone UIActionSheet with multiple red, destructive buttons

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple red/destructive buttons UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360453/multiple-red-destructive-buttons-uiactionsheet)

```
 UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
        initWithTitle:nil
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Today's Data"
        otherButtonTitles:@"Delete Week's Data",@"Delete Month's Data",nil];
```

Is there an easy to have more than 1 red "destructive button" in an iPhone app's UIActionSheet?

I wanted to make 1 "DELETE" button... and then have the actionSheet ask/confirm between 3-4 different "delete choices" (or just 1 cancel).

(Instead of having 4 different DELETE buttons... and have to maintain 4 different actionSheets... 1 for each)

... also... would Apple have a problem with a submission to the appStore with this idea?

Comment: You should go and accept some answers first. 0% is too low

Comment: Vodkhang, please stop responding to my posts.   I'm not interested in playing "give me answering points" games with you... just because you think you deserve them.  I help people... just for the sake of helping them.

Comment: Annette, Vodkhang is right.  This community is self-moderating - people earn the right to do things (up/downvote, edit other people's tags, etc) based on their score.  By marking questions as answered, you're providing valuable feedback to the community on which people deserve those rights.  Additionally, your answered questions will stop appearing in the list of "unanswered" questions, getting out of the way of the questions that truly still need to be answered.

Comment: There is a longer [stackoverflow post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360453/multiple-red-destructive-buttons-uiactionsheet) about multiple destructive buttons.