# performSelector:withObject:, but not with an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to do performSelector:withObject: but where the object is a CGFloat. So it's not actually an object. How can I do this?

the object I am performing the selector on is not mine, I can't modify it.

eg

```
[xyz performSelector:@selector(setOffset:) withObject:2];
```

(after posting I changed what I need to slightly to this:

```
[xyz performSelector:@selector(setOffset:) withObject:CGSizeMake(2,0)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to invoke an arbitrary selector against an object you don't have control over, you could use an [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to set up the selector, target, and arguments, and obtain the return value after the method has been executed.

Generally, though, there are simpler solutions.

Comment: Look at the code in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments  to see how to set up and use NSInvocation with a non-object type.

Answer (score 1):

try use IMP  (A pointer to the start of a method implementation.)

```
SEL setOffsetSEL = @selector(setOffset:);
IMP setOffsetIMP = [XYZClass instanceMethodForSelector:setOffsetSEL];
setOffsetIMP(xyz, setOffsetSEL, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an object to message.   When I've needed to do something like this, I'll create a simple container class, shove the data in an instance and then perform a selector (often @selector(doIt:)) when needed.

If you can target 4.x, you can use blocks for this, too, typically.

(Without knowing more about what exactly you are trying to do, hard to get any more specific.)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. It sounds like he has an object to message, but the argument to the object's method (which you'd normally pass as the "with object" argument) is a float.

Answer (score 0):

> object passed is a CGFloat. So it's not actually an object.

As you wrote immediately after, if you're passed an object, it can't be a `CGFloat`, as `CGFloat` is a `typedef`'ed primitive (`float` or `double`).

If you've been passed a number value as an object, likely you were passed an `NSNumber` somehow.

With zero context to your question, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I think the word "passed" made it confusing. I want to do `[thing performSelector:@selector(someThing:) withObject:1.0f]`

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)value]
```

Comment: This will spectacularly not work. A function expecting a float cannot detect that you have passed an NSNumber and unwrap it for you. So you'll get a garbage float with the same bit pattern as the pointer's value.

Comment: I assumed that the selector was created by the user and the only problem was the performSelector:withObject: call

Comment: If you edit your answer right now I will undown vote it, just add a full stop or something.

Comment: @Jonathan: I edited the answer, so you should be able to undo your vote.