# UIAction with two delete buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I have an ActionSheets with 2 delete buttons, "delete all" and "delete selected item".

Since delete is an destructive behavior, should i definitely keep them as "destructive buttons" or can i keep them as normal buttons without any destructive button at all?

Advice would greatly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would make "delete all" the destructive button.
My anger level falls down quick after I have accidentally deleted one item. But if my whole dataset is gone you better stay away from me.

And there is no need to use the destructive button at all.
You can even start the destruction of the whole world with a normal button.

It might confuse your users, but it's okay to do so. Sometimes "delete all" isn't destructive enough to show the red button. It's up to you.

Comment: Adding a little more to that, is it advisable to confirm the delete operation with an alert view after selection in the action sheet? or can i go fwd and delete the items in the tableview?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps [Multiple red/destructive buttons UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360453/multiple-red-destructive-buttons-uiactionsheet)

I personally think having the "delete all" button alone as destructive and the other as a normal button

Comment: Adding a little more to that, is it advisable to confirm the delete operation with an alert view after selection in the action sheet? or can i go fwd and delete the items in the tableview?